# How to search for the name of the UserProperty in Outlook.MailItems, not their value

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

**BACKGROUND:**

Currently I am searching Outlook.MailItems where their UserProperty (here, "IsProcessed") is equal to its propertyValue (here, true or false).

```
string propertyValue = "true";
string filter = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/IsProcessed LIKE \'%" + propertyValue + "%\'";
```

I am using this filter string in advancedSearch [link to doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.AdvancedSearch)

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

My usecase is to search if these mailItems have any UserProperty assigned where name of UserProperty = "IsProcessed".

Is there any way to do so using similar DASL filter string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to know the GUID. All user properties in OOM use the GUID of `{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` (which is `PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS`).

To see the DASL name of a property, take a look at existing messages with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - select the message, click IMessage button) - when you select a named property (bolded) OutlookSpy will show its GUID, id, and the DASL name.

Comment: what if i use Find() [link1](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/) 
[link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb220350(v=office.12)

Currently I am doing:

 string searchCriteria = "[IsProcessed] = 'True'"; 

where "IsProcessed" is the name of property. 

Is there any way to check if ["UserProperty"] = "IsProcessed" ?

Comment: I tried the following way in Items.Find() 
string searchCriteria = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F LIKE \'%" + propertyName + "%\'";

but it doesn't work. 
Even though it is written in its VB doc:[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find)

Comment: Why would lit work? 0x007D001F is PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_A, so your code is searching if that particular string is present in the MIME headers. It won't be for a user property. Did you look at the messages that your query is supposed to find with OutlookSpy?

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following criteria to get items with a user property set up:

```
string filter = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/IsProcessed IS NOT NULL";
```

or get items with a user property not set:

```
string filter = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/IsProcessed IS NULL";
```

See [Is Null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-query-keywords#is-null) operator in search strings.