# How to search Outlook.MailItems where it does not belong to advancedSearch's result

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, outlook, add-in

**BACKGROUND:**

Currently I am searching for the MailItems which belong to the Result set of advancedSearch() Query.

[link to the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.advancedsearch?view=outlook-pia/)

```cs
Outlook.Search advancedSearch = Application.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, true, advancedSearchTag);
Outlook.Results advancedSearchResults = advancedSearch.Results;

foreach (MailItem item in advancedSearchResults)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.Subject.ToString());
}
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

I want to search and loop on MailItems which doesnot satisfy the "filter" of this advancedSearch() method. Is there any way to do so?

If NO. Is there any work around for it? (either using Find() or Restrict())
My specific case is to search, if UserProperty of each MailItem is "ABC" or not. (not it's value, but the name of the UserProperty)

here, I am using:

```cs
string filter = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} LIKE \'%" + propertyName + "%\'";
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you need? c# code or vb.net code?

Comment: @Simo anything would work as I just need to know the technique, syntax I can find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, prepend your search with "NOT". Secondly, add the "is null" or "is not null" clauses - your search query assumes the property exists on each item. If it doesn't, the result is undefined.

Comment: Do you mean something lilke this? (not tested yet)
string filter = String.Format("http://schemas.microsoft.com//mapi//string//{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} >= '{0}'", propertyName);

Comment: No, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{0B63E350-9CCC-11D0-BCDB-00805FCCCE04}/YouPropertyName" IS NOT NULL

Comment: And as I have already mentioned in a reply to your other question, you cannot search for a property name. Only for a property value.

Comment: I tested it today & I was able to search. Will update the other question with the working code snippet once this is done. 
Snippet present in my current question works fine. I just want to negate it now.

Comment: No, it does not work, and that is why you are having these problems. Your search query searches for a named property with GUID = {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} and no name (which makes no sense) having a value contained in the propertyName variable.

Comment: has described the correct answer here in the comments. Also, in the previous question that I posted. You can check it's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468148/how-to-search-for-the-name-of-the-userproperty-in-outlook-mailitems-not-their-v thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko